# Modifying an Erlang Record

Tags: erlang, record, erl

I know that a record in Erlang cannot be changed once it has been set. I am attempting to use a record to increase a value.

```
add_new_num() ->
    Number = random:uniform(6),
    STR = #adder{value = 7},
    New = add(STR, Number).         

add(#adder{value =V} = Adder, Value) ->
    Adder#adder{value = V + Value}.
```

When running `add_new_num()` I will always get `7 + Number`. This is not what I want. I want to get it to do the following.

```
add_new_num() -> 7 + Number = Val
add_new_num() -> Val + Number = Val2
add_new_num() -> Val2 + Number = Val3
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Think about where you want to store the value: Erlang doesn't have "static variables" like C, so the function itself cannot remember the value.

You could pass the current record as an argument to `add_new_num`, and get the updated record from its return value. You could keep a process running, and send messages to query it for the current value and to ask it to increase the value.  Or you could store the value in an [ETS table](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html), or even [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html).

Comment: How would I go to update record from return value @legoscia